# How do I read a text file as a string?

Tags: python, text-files

Below are the codes I have tried to read the text in the text file in a method called `check_keyword()`

```
def check_keyword():
    with open(unknown.txt, "r") as text_file:
        unknown = text_file.readlines()

    return unknown
```

This is how i called the method:

```
dataanalysis.category_analysis.check_keyword()
```

The text in the text file:

```
Hello this is a new text file
```

There is no output for the method above :((

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`text_file.readlines()` returns a list of strings containing the lines in the file. If you want only a string, not a list of the lines, use `text_file.read()` instead.

You also have another problem in your code, you are trying to open `unknown.txt`, but you should be trying to open `'unknown.txt'` (a string with the file name).

Comment: ohh okie I have changed but there are still no output of the text file...  @Tomothy32

Comment: Are you getting any error or just no return value? Also, make sure the file name is correct and the file is not empty.

Comment: @School Can you try printing `unknown`? This should work, so please post your updated code.

Comment: @Tomoth32 I tried printing out unknown but it didnt give me anything

Comment: I cannot see any possible reason why this would not work. Please post your updated code.

Comment: If i were to call the method nothing prints out but if i were to move the codes out of the method it does print out ...@Tomothy32

Comment: This then is not part of the original question and not a problem to do with the `check_keyword()` function. This means that, in your code, you are never actually running into `dataanalysis.category_analysis.check_keyword()`, so the code in `check_keyword` is never being run.

Answer (score 25):

You can do this as follows:

```
with open("foo","r") as f:
    string = f.read()
```

Comment: then how should I write it and return it in my method because I tried to print(string) but there is no output... @power.puffed

Comment: def check_keyword():
    with open("foo.txt", "r") as text_file:
        unknown = text_file.read()

    return unknown

Printing this as: print(check_keyword()) gives correct output for me, using python 3

Comment: it returns me nothing :(( @power.puffed

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `text_file.readlines()` use `text_file.read()` which will give you contents of files in string format rather than list.

Answer (score 2):

The code is just a working code based on all the above answers.

```
def check_keyword():
    with open("unknown.txt", "r") as text_file:
         unknown = text_file.read()

     return unknown

check_keyword()
```

Answer (score -3):

Actually i have made a  whole lib to make that work easy for all

```
from filemod import reader
data=reader("file.txt"))
print(data)
```

Comment: This answer ist not clear. Where does the module `filemod` come from? Do you use an implementation by your own? How can any else use this implementation, if you don't share the source?