# Python: print() not outputting translated str(), outputs original line of code

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm working on a basic Biology program to help me better learn python, but I'm hung up on outputting my converted strings. I have a DNA input that is being translated to an RNA output, but my RNA output reads as "<_io.AextIOWrapper name='input.txt' mode='+r' encoding='cp1252'>" instead of the RNA. My DNA string outputs fine, so I know the program is getting the data correctly. I'm at wits end trying to convert the string back to ASCII to try and use the same print(RNA.read()) function, but I know that's not the proper way.

```
inputbuffer = open("input.txt", "+r")
print(inputbuffer.read())
DNA = str(inputbuffer)
translation = {65: 85, 84: 65, 71: 67, 67: 71}
RNA = DNA.translate(translation)
print(RNA)
```

Comment: `inputbuffer` is the file handle that you got from `open()`, it is _not_ the contents of the file (which you read, printed, and then did nothing else with)

Comment: You need to assign the output of `inputbuffer.read()` to `DNA` i.e. `DNA = inputbuffer.read()` and then translate that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a text file as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204752/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-as-a-string)

Comment: Once that was changed, there is no secondary output from the RNA translation

Answer (score -1):

The solution was as provided by Nick and Pranav, **except** that I had to eliminate the line `print(inputbuffer.read())` and replace it with `print(DNA)` after `DNA` was defined.

Comment: While this answers the question, this might not be helpful to future developers who visit the site